# Broadcast-streaming of live audio contents between iPods

Tags: ios, live, audio-streaming, broadcast, ipod-touch

After a lot of searching in the web I am going to ask here my question:

I want to stream audio between iPods WITHOUT or with less buffering. I am thinking of something like RTP or WebRTC for iOS.

The app which I will develop, enables one iPod to capture the microphone and to stream the audio to the other 50-100 iPods (Broadcast), but all this has to be LIVE.

One speaker's talk is recorded live and the other iPod's can hear the speaker at the same time with very less delay...

Is such a thing possible? Are there frameworks or software existing to handle this? I prefer Objective-C and HTML5.

I would be really happy getting any help. Thanks in forward.

Comment: Have you thought about using Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes but I don't think that it will work with Blutooth, because one iPod has to stream his live-audio to 50-100 iPods. Technically not really the best way I think.

Comment: and I am not sure if Bluetooth supports live streaming. The streaming has to run continuously.

Comment: 50-100?! Wow then I'm not sure it'll work... Sorry. It might, but as you said it's not ideal